# Gradle println prints when it is not called

Tags: gradle

My goal is to have a message printed to the console whenever the `idea` task is run, but unfortunately the message is printed whenever anything is run. Why are the print lines executing when the `idea` task is not being run? How can I display a message only when the `idea` task is executed?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

task hello << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}

tasks.idea() {
    println '*********************************************************'
    println '* You should open build.gradle as a native project from *'
    println '* within IntelliJ.                                      *'
    println '*********************************************************'
}
```

Output of the command `gradle hello`

```
*********************************************************
* You should open build.gradle as a native project from *
* within IntelliJ.                                      *
*********************************************************
:hello
Hello world!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.846 secs
```

**Working Solution**

```
tasks.getByPath('idea') << {
    println '*********************************************************'
    println '* You should open build.gradle as a native project from *'
    println '* within IntelliJ.                                      *'
    println '*********************************************************'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task

Comment: See also: [Gradle always does println from any task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to put your `println`s into an action and add it to the `idea` task. The following example shows the use of the `doFirst` action:

```
ideaProject.doFirst {
    println '*********************************************************'
    println '* You should open build.gradle as a native project from *'
    println '* within IntelliJ.                                      *'
    println '*********************************************************'
}
```

There's a specific reason your code is executed before the `idea` task is run: It's evaluated as configuration code executed during the configuration phase of [Gradle's build lifecycle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html). Only actions are executed during the execution phase. Your `hello` task does that.

EDIT: `idea` is `org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModel` in this context and not the task.

Answer (score 3):

If You want to force gradle to print some messages but only in execution phase, move `println` commands to `doFirst` or `doLast`. Example for war task:

```
war {
    doFirst {
        println "Packing module/project to " + archiveName + " ..."
    }
    manifest {
        // attributes ... 
    }
    // other commands ...
    doLast {
        println "Packing done. See target directory."
    }
}
```