# Gradle always does println from any task

Tags: java, gradle, println

I have simple `build.gradle` (or any `build.gradle` with task that has `println`)

```
println GradleVersion.current().prettyPrint()

task task1{
    println 'task1 starting'
}
```

Now when I run `$ gradle build` I always see tasks executing or print output

```
task1 starting
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.291 secs
```

**Why there is always output from `println` inside tasks?**

Comment: Duplicate: [Gradle println prints when it is not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051140/gradle-println-prints-when-it-is-not-called)

Comment: it appears to me that both questions are asking "Why is println ALWAYS printing?". The goals of the questions are different, however the underlying question is about the same Gradle behavior. I do not think either question should be closed as a duplicate, but I think any subsequent readers will benefit from cross-linking in the comments.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If You have the following piece of code:

```
task task1 {
    println 'task1 starting'
}
```

You're in *configuration* phase of a task. This phase is run during script evaluation. If You'd like to print something while task is executed You need to add an *action* for task.

It looks like:

```
task task1 << {
   println 'task1 action'
}
```

This piece of code will be evaluated while the task is being run. `<<` is exactly the same as invoking `doLast` method on Task's object. You can add many actions.

**EDIT**
I also highly encourage you to read [this](https://link.medium.com/EosAxEelxX) blog post.

Answer (score 8):

from Chapter 55. The Build Lifecycle http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

```
// in `settings.gradle`
// println 'This is executed during the initialization phase.'

println 'This is executed during the configuration phase.'

task configure {
    println 'This is also executed during the configuration phase.'
}

task execute << {
    println 'This is executed during the execution phase.'
}
```

run with `gradle help`

output:

```
This is executed during the initialization phase.
This is executed during the configuration phase.
This is also executed during the configuration phase.
:help

Welcome to Gradle 1.10.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.882 secs
```