# Purpose of << in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I starting playing around gradle and trying to understand the purpose of <<.

On executing gradle -q task0 when build.gradle contains gave me `task 0`

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" <<{
        println "task $counter"
    }
}
```

where as executing gradle -q test{0123} when build.gradle contains

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" {
        println "task $counter"
    }
}
```

returning

```
task 0
task 1
task 2
task 3
```

Can someone help in understanding purpose of `<<`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<<` it will execute the print lines when the task is executed and not having it executes the print lines when the task is configured.

This can effect your output since the Gradle Lifecycle is Initialization > Configuration > Execution.

For example if your `build.gradle` contains:

```
task "task0" << {
    println "task 0"
}

task "task1" {
    println "task 1"
}
```

Then if you execute `task0` you will get:

```
> gradlew -q task0
task 1
task 0
```

Even though you would only expect `task 0` to print. While if you execute `task1` you get:

```
> gradlew -q task1
task 1
```

This is because `task1` is printing out during configuration which even though you are not running it, the whole `build.gradle` file gets read in during the configuration phase to determine what gets executed. You could even go:

```
> gradlew clean
task 1
```

And you get your output from `task1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is what **<<** means. It is predefined shift left operator and with it we say to a Gradle task. "Gradle task, I want closure which is after << to be put as your last action".So with

```
task "taskHello" <<{
        println "Hello Gradle action"
}
```

you say in my build I have a task, which name is taskHello and I want when excecute it with

```
gradle taskHello
```

To do action

```
   {
    println "Hello Gradle action"
   }
```

<< is a syntax sugar short for doLast{}, so you can rewrite your task like this:

```
4.times { counter ->
    task "task$counter" {
       doLast{
        println "task $counter"
    }
  }
}
```