# Gradle task list

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Why does the followig code not add a task to the build group:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
task hello << {
    description = 'To say hello to a task list'
    group = 'build'
}
```

The fragment of output of gradle tasks:

```
[...]
Other tasks
-----------
hello
```

but the following does:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
task hello {
    description = 'To say hello to a task list'
    group = 'build'
}
```

Output of the gradle task command:

```
Build tasks
-----------
assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend
on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
classes - Assembles classes 'main'.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
hello - To say hello to a task list
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
testClasses - Assembles classes 'test'.
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because the first variant is short-hand for:

```
task hello

hello.doLast {
    description = 'To say hello to a task list'
    group = 'build'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because You're mixing task *configuration* with task *action*, for details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task/23288564#23288564).

In this piece of code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
task hello << {
    description = 'To say hello to a task list'
    group = 'build'
}
```

You're in *action* scope, note the `<<` operator which indicates it. `description` and `group` from task are available in *action* but modifying them brings no effect.

Here You're in *configuration* scope where `description` and `group` variables are available for modification.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
task hello {
    description = 'To say hello to a task list'
    group = 'build'
}
```