# Gradle Task Configuration vs Task Execution

Tags: gradle

What is the difference between the code below?

```
task A {
 println 'configuration'
}

task B << {
 println 'action'
}
```

I believe it has something to do with evaluation.

ie task A is always evaluated
whereas task B is only evaluated when its executed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle always does println from any task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task)

Comment: @Opal I started looking at duplicate first before answering (since sure this explanation has been given multiple times before), but could not find one at that time. Besides, I guess the title of this one makes it better an easier to find "similar" issues...

Comment: Sure. But a question with the exactly same point occurs here every month. It's time to start marking such questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed: the 'println' statement of your task A will be executed during 'configuration' phase, whereas the 'println' statement of taks B will only be executed during 'execution' phase (assuming task B is run, directly or indirectly via task dependencies)

For more info, checkout: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html. Section 56.2 has a nice example (also demonstrating the third phase, being the 'initialization' phase, BTW)

Note: the "<<" is a shorthand notation for "doLast"