# How to order the 'running' of configuration tasks in Gradle?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I've currently got a configuration task being depended on by an execution task that I am calling from command-line, i.e.

```
task deployTest(dependsOn: [build, assembleForTest]) << {
    ...
}
```

This task should essentially grab the files I've assembled in **assembleForTest** and then deploy them (ssh, etc.)

My **assembleForTest** code:

```
task assembleForTest(type: Sync) {
    fileMode = 0775
    from ("scripts") {
        include "**/*.cgi"
        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, 
        tokens: [programName: programName, 
                 version: version, 
                 dbServer: dbServerTest,
                 deployDir: deployDirTest])
    }
    from files("scripts/" + programName + ".cgi") 
    from files("build/libs/" + programName + "-" + version + ".jar")
    into ("build/" + programName)   
}
```

But the problem is: My project gets built AFTER this configuration task **assembleForTest** has run. i.e. it will try build after the assembly is finished, which means an outdated (or nonexistant) deployment is attempted.

Gradle has some of the worst documenting I've seen, I have worked with it for a while and I still don't understand the ideal setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't that solve your problem?

```
task assembleForTest(type: Sync, dependsOn: build) {
    /* configuration phase, evaluated always and before execution phase of any task */
    ...
}

task deployTest(dependsOn: assembleForTest) << {
    /* execution phase, evaluated only if the task is invoked and after configuration phase for all tasks has been finished */
    ...
}
```

EDIT: I added comments within example. Note that the 1st task is provided with configuration while the 2nd is provided with action. The switch is done with left shift operator. Alternative syntax, especially helpful to combine both phases definition, looks as follows:

```
task plop() {
    // some configuration
    ...
    doLast {
        // some action
        ...
    }
}
```

If you put `println` in place of 'some configuration' it prints always regardless what task is invoked, as that's evaluated in configuration phase.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, though I was trying with some actions as well, such as println. Is println not capable of performing between configuration tasks? This seems to have solved the issue, which I thought it would have a while ago, but it didn't solve all my requirements at the time.

If I added `println "Assemble"`, it appears at the start of configuration? i.e.

`Assemble
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE`

Comment: Ah! :compileJava, :processResources etc. are part of the execution phase? i.e. they are called during the execution phase of each task, not configuration.

Comment: Any task has its configuration phase as well as execution phase. Statements for the tasks in the sample you provided (basically three dots in my proposed solution) are evaluated in different phases(!). The thing which affects that is left shift operator in task definition. It kind of 'switches' where the body of a closure provided goes to. `task foo() { println 'configuration phase' }` is evaluated always before `task bar() << { println 'execution phase' }` regardless which way around you make foo and bar dependent on each other. Perhaps that's why 'spying' with println confused you.

Comment: Have a look here in the border titled 'Don't forget about the build phases' https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html
EDIT: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282364/gradle-task-configuration-vs-task-execution

Comment: Thanks @topr. I understand both of these. I think the confusion on println "working" in configuration phase, but the task name being printed later on at the start of execution phase.