# Why does bootRun execute when running the build task?

Tags: java, gradle

**build.gradle**

```
bootRun {
    println 'BOOTRUN'
}
```

Perhaps I'm being ignorant here. But when I run `./gradlew build`, my log statement "BOOTRUN" shows up in the output. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here?

Comment: answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282364/gradle-task-configuration-vs-task-execution .  In your case, your `println` statement inside the `bootRun` extension configuration will also be executed during the *configuration* phase

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that!