# Update value according to build type in Gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I am using Android Studio with Gradle build.
In my *build.gradle*, I want a variable's value to be different for different build type:

```
ext {
    //By default, the value of myVar is 'debug'
    myVar = 'debug'
}

android {
   buildTypes {
       release {    
            //update value of myVar to 'release'
            project.ext.set("myVar","release")
        }


        debug {
             //update value of myVar to 'debug'
             project.ext.set("myVar","debug")
        }

    }
}

//I defined a task to check the value of myVar
task checkVar () {
   println "My var is $myVar"
}

check.dependsOn(checkVar)
```

When I run command `gradle clean assembleRelease` , I expected to see a print out text `My var is release`. But, I see `My var is debug` . Why the value of `myVar` is not changed to `release` ?

What I want to achieve is to get the current build type during execution. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: When `myVar` is printed at execution time (in task action) it behaves the same as it's printed during configuration time?

Comment: What do you mean 'configuration time'?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task/23288564#23288564

Comment: can you elaborate what you're trying to achieve with this so we can find a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as it is a project scoped variable. the build type blocks are just configuration, so what really happens here (a bit simplified though):

1. You declare a variable named 'myVar' with a default value 'debug' assigned
2. You run the release configuration block and set the value of 'myVar' to 'release'
3. You run the debug configuration block and set the value of 'myVar' back to 'debug'

when executing the 'checkVar' task, the last assigned value is printed.

FYI: you can simplify 2. and 3. by just calling `project.myVar = 'whatever'`

Comment: Then, how can I address this problem?

Comment: What do you use the 'myVar' variable in for in your build? Keep in mind that you can build both (debug and relase) apks in one build-run

Comment: my custom task needs to know the current build type, and pass that to a shell script as an argument. The task executes the shell script.

Comment: usually you would one task that does this per build variant. I updated my answer to show you an example.

Comment: Seems you haven't updated your answer, could you please give an example about "one task does it per build variant" ? Thanks.