# Gradle copy task runs on clean

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I have a gradle Copy task that copies assets from the project directory into the build directory:

```
tasks.register("copyAssets", Copy) {
    def fromDir = "${project.projectDir.toString()}/../assets"
    def toDir = "${project.buildDir.toString()}/assets"

    println "Copying assets"
    println "   from $fromDir"
    println "   into $toDir"

    from fromDir
    into toDir
}

build.dependsOn copyAssets
run.dependsOn copyAssets
```

This works, but somehow it not only runs on *build* and *run*, but also on *clean*.

If I remove both lines with `dependsOn`, it doesn't run on *build*, *run*, or *clean*. But as soon as I put the line with `build.dependsOn` in, the task runs on *build*, *run*, and *clean*. If, on the other hand, I remove `build.dependsOn` and put in `run.dependsOn` instead, the outcome is the same: The task runs on *build*, *run*, and *clean*.

How does `dependsOn` work? How can I make it to run on *build* and *run*, but not on *clean*?

I use gradle wrapper, and it's a multi-module project, i.e.

```
./gradlew main:clean
./gradlew main:build
./gradlew main:run
```

The task is in the *main* module only, not inside the top-level `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, as it mixes two of the most common mistakes or confusion made when using Gradle:

- confusion between task configuration and execution phases
- misuse of task configuration avoidance feature.

##### Task configuration vs execution phase

Lots of SO questions are dealing with this topic , just search "configuration vs execution phase" for answers explaining this in details.
One example : [Gradle always does println from any task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288470/gradle-always-does-println-from-any-task)

In your example: you say that `copyAssets` task is also executed when running `clean` task but in fact it's not **executed**, it's just **configured**.

Executing `gradle build`:

```
> Configure project :sample
Copying assets              <==== the println  are executed, because  they are part of the Configuration phase
   from src
   into /path/sample/build/

> Task :sample:assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sample:check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sample:copyAssets     <<<=====   task copyAssets is executed as expected
> Task :sample:build
```

Executing `gradle clean`:

```
> Configure project :sample
Copying assets     <==== the println  are still executed, because  they are part of the Configuration phase
   from src
   into /path/sample/build/

> Task :sample:clean    <<<=====   task copyAssets is NOT executed, only clean task is.
```

You can check that when calling `clean`, you assets will not be copied, you will just see the println in console.
Note that you will also see these println when executing any other task ( e.g.  `gradle help`, `gradle tasks` ...)

##### Task configuration avoidance issue

You are declaring your task using the [`register`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html#register-java.lang.String-) API,
which enables [Task configuraiton avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) feature.
So, in theory, the `copyAssets` should be configured only if it must be executed (=> only when you invoke  `build` or  `run` tasks in your example)

So why is it configured (but not executed) when executing `clean` in your example ?

This is due to the way you are declaring the tasks dependencies , as explained in the [Task configuration avoidance pitfalls](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:task_configuration_avoidance_pitfalls) section/

```
build.dependsOn copyAssets
```

=> this will eagerly create and configure the `build` task, and in cascade will also create and configure the dependent `copyAssets` task.

There are several ways to fix this, given in the link above.
One example:

```
// replace 
build.dependsOn copyAssets

// with:
build.dependsOn tasks.named("copyAssets")
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah! you have put in the default task closure - the steps happen at task initialisation.

```
tasks.register("copyAssets", Copy) {
    doLast() {
        def fromDir = "${project.projectDir.toString()}/../assets"
        def toDir = "${project.buildDir.toString()}/assets"

        println "Copying assets"
        println "   from $fromDir"
        println "   into $toDir"

        from fromDir
        into toDir
    }
}
```

read - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#header

Comment: This doesn't work. Now the task is never called.